# Document Set Welcome Page Edit Properties does not display my columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

On my Document Set Welcome Page there is a link for "Edit Properties" but only 2 properties display despite the fact I have 8 properties that are optional.  How do I get all 8 properties to display when I click on Edit Properties ?

Note if I click on Edit Properties Content Type Name and Name are the only 2 properties visible.  If I click View Properties then ALL properties are visible.

I have SP 2013 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Go to your Document library settings page.

2) In the content type section, click on the document set content type.

[image]

3) Now, usually in the document set, it has only two default columns, Name and Description. So, if you want to add your own custom columns, click on `add from existing list or site columns.` as below

[image]

4) After you add your columns, it will look somewhat as below:

[image]

5) Once this is done, these columns will be available for edit from the document set edit properties link as below:

[image]

Have tested it at my end and its showing these properties on the edit page.

The reason behind that is that those columns are not associated with the document set content type. Once you follow these steps, it will associate these columns to the content type and they will show up on the edit properties.

**Update based on comments:**

As you mentioned that it works in a different test library, one reason for this is that somebody must have hidden those fields in the edit form.

To show those fields in edit form, you can run the below powershell and check:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "https://site-url"    
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Listname")    
if($list)    
{    
    $field = $list.Fields["FieldName"]    
    $field.ShowInEditForm = $true    
    $field.Update()    
}
```

Comment: It still does not work.  If I create a test library as you did above it works.  I am wondering if my library is corrupted ?  Any suggestions to fix ?

Comment: Check the updated answer, it could be that somebody must have hidden those fields in edit form, so to show them, you can run the powershell command

Comment: I dont have access to Powershell...is there another way I can make those fields visible in the edit form...